# C++ string.empty not working

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to use `.empty()` so pressing enter in the following code will not execute the if statement and the do-while loop will break. When I try this code, hitting enter does nothing: it just continues indenting until I enter more data. I looked up `.empty()` and I think I am using it correctly. Why isn't this code working?

```
void Student::read()
{
string g = " ";

cout << "Enter the students name: ";
getline(cin, new_name);
cout << endl;

do
{
    cout << "Please enter a letter grade <E to quit>: ";
    cin >> g;

    if(!g.empty())
    {
        addGrade(g);
    }
}while(!g.empty());
}
```

Comment: @billz that has nothing to do with it, `cin >> g` will overwrite the previous contents of `g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is nothing to do with `string.empty()`, it is this line:

```
cin >> g;
```

That operation is whitespace delimited. That is to say, it skips all leading whitespace, and then once it has started consuming non-whitespace characters, it stops on the next whitespace if finds. So you can just press enter all day long, and it will be ignored, because pressing enter causes a newline character (`'\n'`), which is whitespace.

If you want line oriented input, use `getline` instead of `operator>>`.

```
getline(cin, g);
```

Comment: yes that fixed it! Thank you, cant believe i overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

std:;string:empty() is working as expected in this. As Benjamin pointed out instead if you use `getline(cin, g);` in place of `cin>>g` you can achieve what you are expected:

```
int main()
{
string g = " ";
std::string new_name;
cout << "Enter the students name: ";
getline(cin, new_name);
cout << endl;

do
{
    cout << "Please enter a letter grade <E to quit>: ";
    getline(cin, g);

    if(!g.empty())
    {
        std::cout<<"here";
        //addGrade(g);
    }
}while(!g.empty());

return 0;
}
```